# Platform::Collections::Vector sorting

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, c++-cx

In Metro Style apps sometimes we use `Platform::Collections::Vector` to hold elements used in a ListView.

How to sort a `Platform::Collections::Vector`?

I'm aware there are plenty of structures in std that can be sorted but I was wondering if there was some method for `Platform::Collections::Vector` other than writing your own sort function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually something like the below should also work:

```
auto vec = ref new Platform::Collections::Vector<T^>();
std::sort(begin(vec), end(vec));
```

Comment: can you use the `std` with `CX` types?

Comment: you can use the std algorithms on CX containers

Comment: the compiler don't allow the use of begin and end in this vec

Comment: I designed and implemented <collection.h>, and I can confirm that Raman is correct. After including <collection.h>, calling unqualified non-member begin()/end() on a WFC::IVector<T>^ or PC::Vector<T>^ will return a PC::VectorIterator<T>, an ordinary C++ class that's a random-access STL iterator. It can be used with STL algorithms like std::sort(). Note that std::sort() will want to compare your elements with op<, so if your elements (like X^) don't support that, you'll need to provide a custom comparator.

Comment: @ppaulojr I was just tripped up by this for Visual Studio 2015 RC.  My problem was that I was using std::begin but the non-member begin functions for these collections live in the WFC namespace.  Removing std:: like in the answer above fixed my issue since I have a using namespace statement for the WFC namespace.  Perhaps this is the problem you had.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any suitable answer so I used this workaround.

It's a simple `quicksort` over a `Platform::Collections::Vector`

```
void swap (Platform::Collections::Vector<T^>^ vec, int pos1, int pos2)
{
   T^ tmp = vec->GetAt(pos1);
   vec->SetAt(pos1, vec->GetAt(pos2));
   vec->SetAt(pos2,tmp);
}

int compare (T^ c1, T^ c2)
{
   int c = wcscmp (c1->Title->Data(),c2->Title->Data());
   return -c;
}

int PartitionVec (int left, int right, 
                            Platform::Collections::Vector<T^>^ vec)
{
   int i,j;
   i = left;
   for (int j = left + 1; j <= right; ++j)
   {
       if (compare (vec->GetAt(j),vec->GetAt(left)) > 0)
       {
               ++i;
           swap (vec,i,j);
       }
    }
    swap (vec,left,i);
    return i;
}

void QuickSortVec (Platform::Collections::Vector<T^>^ vec,
                                           int start, int end)
{
   if (end > start)
   {
       int pivot_point;
       pivot_point = PartitionVec (start, end, vec);
       QuickSortVec (vec,start,pivot_point - 1);
       QuickSortVec (vec, pivot_point + 1, end);
    } 
}
```